# Estructura de proyecto python

Tags: python, estructuras, librería

Hola mi duda es la siguiente, ¿existe alguna manera estándar a la hora de estructurar un proyecto python en distintos paquetes al hacer una librería?.

me refiero a carpetas tales como utils, commons, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No encuentro un PEP (Python Enhancement Proposal) que haga referencia a ese tema, así que la respuesta sería no, no existe una convención oficial al respecto; al margen de utilizar `__init__.py` que requiere Python para que se considere un paquete. Si que existe PEP 8 con referencia a la manera preferida por la comunidad sobre el estilo del código.

Está en inglés: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions